# SQL Custom selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write an sql which gives the following result. Is this possible?
I tried with UNION but it only works for one record.

```
col1  | col2 | col3 | col4 
---------------------------
  A   |  10  |      |
      |   2  | val1 | val2  
      |   5  | val3 | val4
      |   3  | val5 | val6
  B   |  11  |      |
      |   3  | val7 | val8  
      |   5  | val9 | val10
      |   3  | val0 | val12
```

Here my query :

```
SELECT a.val1, NULL val2, a.val3 FROM table1 a 
WHERE a.val1 = 'A' 
UNION 
SELECT NULL val1, b.val2, b.val3 FROM table2 b 
WHERE b.val1 = 'A' ;
```

maybe this will make the question more clear.

imagine if I run the query:

```
SELECT a.val1, NULL val2, a.val3 FROM table1 a 
UNION 
SELECT NULL val1, b.val2, b.val3 FROM table2 b ;
```

I want the result set to be as the figure above.

```
col1  | col2 | col3 | col4 
---------------------------
  A   |  10  |      |
      |   2  | val1 | val2  
      |   5  | val3 | val4
      |   3  | val5 | val6
  B   |  11  |      |
      |   3  | val7 | val8  
      |   5  | val9 | val10
      |   3  | val0 | val12
```

Comment: please show your table construct

Comment: `SQL` refers to which RDBMS here :) ?

Comment: Can you also explain the result?

Comment: this is in Oracle. and this is the sql i tried
SELECT a.val1,
       NULL val2,
       a.val3       
FROM table1 a
WHERE a.val1 = 'A'
UNION 
SELECT NULL val1,
       b.val2,
       b.val3       
FROM  table2 b
WHERE b.val1 = 'A' ;

Comment: Please write code into the question as an edit, rather than in comments - it's impossible to read here.

Comment: Yea, you can use calculate row index partitioned by col1 (a, b, c, etc) and wrap it all in a subquery and set col1 to null when row index is greater than 1

Comment: Shouldn't the second filter be `WHERE b.val1 = 'B'`?

Comment: @gmm i kinda want this result if i run the query for 
WHERE b.val1 IN ('A' , 'B')

Comment: I'm a bit confused. There seems to be a disconnect between the sample output and the query.  The sample output has four columns, but the query only has three columns.  Also, the 'WHERE b.val1 IN ('A', 'B')` isn't in the question.  Can you elaborate (explain the structures of the two real tables, what kind of data you're dealing with, more information about the expected output, etc.)?

Comment: You will Not get a result Set containing 'B' in col1 if you nullify this Data in the second select of your Query.

Comment: gmm ,collapsar i edited the question. hope it'll be more clear

Answer (score 2):

either a rollup or regular group can do this, but you still haven't accounted for `col2`. where did that come from, as in your sql snippets, you don't have it at all.

```
SQL> create table yourtab(col1, col2, col3, col4)
  2  as
  3  select 'A', 2, 'val1', 'val2' from dual
  4  union all select 'A', 5, 'val3', 'val4' from dual
  5  union all select 'A', 3, 'val5', 'val6' from dual
  6  union all select 'B', 3, 'val7', 'val8' from dual
  7  union all select 'B', 5, 'val9', 'val10' from dual
  8  union all select 'B', 3, 'val11', 'val12' from dual;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> select col1, sum(col2) col2, col3, col4
  2    from yourtab
  3   group by col1, rollup(col3, col4)
  4  having (grouping_id(col3), grouping_id(col4)) in ((0,0),(1,1))
  5  order by col1, grouping_id(col3) desc;

C       COL2 COL3  COL4
- ---------- ----- -----
A         10
A          5 val3  val4
A          3 val5  val6
A          2 val1  val2
B         11
B          3 val7  val8
B          5 val9  val10
B          3 val11 val12

8 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select col1, col2, col3, col4
  2    from (select col1, col2, col3, col4, 2 grp
  3            from yourtab
  4          union all
  5          select col1, sum(col2), null, null, 1 grp
  6            from yourtab
  7           group by col1)
  8   order by col1, grp;

C       COL2 COL3  COL4
- ---------- ----- -----
A         10
A          5 val3  val4
A          3 val5  val6
A          2 val1  val2
B         11
B          3 val11 val12
B          5 val9  val10
B          3 val7  val8

8 rows selected.
```